# pandas dataframe header relation to sql table header

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I have a DataFrame with 100+ columns that I am trying to write into a SQL table.
This is a daily process with a full data load, and it looks like so:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = 'extract_' + str(now)[:10]
output = "./output"

sql_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(output,filename + '.csv'))
server = "redshift+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (USER,PASSWORD,HOST,str(PORT),DATABASE)
engine = sa.create_engine(server, connect_args={'sslmode': 'verify-ca'}, use_batch_mode=True)
conn = engine.raw_connection()

conn.cursor().execute("truncate table")
%time sql_df.to_sql('table', engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

I am getting the following error: `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "column" of relation "table" does not exist`.

Can someone clarify why does `to_sql` compare the headers of the DataFrame and the table (and doesn't allow operation unless all match), rather than just inserting values appropriately excluding header row? If instead of writing DF to SQL I upload csv to S3, then use "copy"- there are no errors..

Anything I can do for it to ignore headers and just insert values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the input df to match the names in the table like this (where db_cols is your database column names), I think this should work for your MySQLdb situation:

```
db_cols = list(pd.read_sql('...')) # where ... is your table will return columns as list

(sql_df
 .rename(columns=dict(zip(sql_df.columns, db_cols)))
 .to_sql(name="table",
         con=alch_engine,
         if_exists="append",
         index=False,
         index_label=None))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The documentation for sqlalchemy doesnt work for some reason http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html.. How can I get `db_cols` for the given table `table`?

Comment: In this construct, how does `cursor.description` know to look at table `table` specifically? Also the `len(cursor.description)` throwing a `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` for me. I think I will just use `pd.read_sql().columns`

Comment: if it returns the table as you would expect use your method! I can always edit this, but if you just mean assigning the variable as `db_cols = pd.read_sql().columns` then this does not return an error, it just returns an index object not a list.